# How does .Any() access entity property when built with an expression tree?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

First of all, this code works but I don't understand why it works. This question is asking why I can access a property in an expression tree when I don't think I should.

Let's start by establishing context.

### Context

I set up two example classes that are included in my dbcontext. They do not have virtual navigation properties. This is a limitation of my legacy dbcontext. The entities in my context are different but I'm using these as an example.

```cs
class Person 
{
    int PersonId {get; set;}
    string FirstName {get; set;}
}

class Address
{
    int AddressId {get; set;}
    string Address {get; set;}
    string City {get; set;}
    string State {get; set;}
    string Zip {get; set;}
    int PersonId {get; set;}
}
```

Let's say that I have a function that returns type `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>` This function helps build expressions that are used by entity framework.
I need to build a filter that "joins" `address` to `person` using an `Any`. The predicate version of this would look something like this.

```cs
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> myFilter = x => myDbContext.Address.Any(y => y.PersonId == x.PersonId && y.City == "New York");
```

Since I need to join to various tables that aren't necessarily the `Address` table, I was able to build this with a generic Expression Tree like this:

```cs
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> BuildMyExpression<T>(IQueryable<T> passedInGenericQueryable)
{
    // This variable is passed in to the function. It's a generic but I'm showing the concrete type here for this example.
    //IQueryable<Address> passedInGenericQueryable;
    
    // This build an expression tree for y.City == "New York" but I omitted the details because my question isn't about this
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> compareCity = MagicFunction<T>("New York", "City");
    
    var personParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "Person");
    var addressParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "Address"); // I named this address for readability but it could be several different types
    
    // Compares the PersonId on the Person table and any other table that has a PersonId property
    var personIdEqual = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(personParam, "PersonId"),
        Expression.Property(addressParam, "PersonId")
    );
    
    // Ands the city comparison and the personId comparison
    var andedExpressions = Expression.AndAlso(
        personIdEqual,
        Expression.Invoke(compareCity, addressParam)
    );
    
    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(andedExpressions, addressParam);
    
    
    // Create an expression tree to represent the Any method on IQueryable<Address>
    var anyMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
        .Where(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
        .Single()
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
    
    var callAnyExpression = Expression.Call(
        anyMethod,
        Expression.Constant(passedInGenericQueryable),
        lambdaExpression
    );
    
    Expression<Func<Person, bool>> fullExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(callAnyExpression, personParam);
    
    
    return fullExpression;
}
```

### Question

My question is specifically about the lines that builds the `Any` method.

```cs
// Create an expression tree to represent the Any method on IQueryable<Address>
var anyMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    .Single()
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
        
var callAnyExpression = Expression.Call(
        anyMethod,
        Expression.Constant(passedInGenericQueryable),
        lambdaExpression
    );
```

How are these lines able to access the properties on the `Person` entity?

If I look at the definition of the `Any` method it looks like this:

```cs
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
```

It's an extension method that takes in an `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>` and returns a `bool` When I'm building my expression, I pass in `IQueryable<Address>` but it accesses a member on `Person`
E.G.

```cs
var personIdEqual = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(personParam, "PersonId"),
        Expression.Property(addressParam, "PersonId")
    );
```

If the collection it's operating on is `IQueryable<TSource>` (`Address` in this case), how is it able to access the `PersonId` property on `Person`?

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364344/filtering-but-property-and-child-entity-property) but not quite the same.

Comment: It do not understand question. You have parameter expression `personParam`  of type `Person` and you just ask that you need member access from parameter `personParam`. No matter with `IQueryable` you have. You have two lambda functions and each has parameter. One Lambda inside other.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv when I build the `Any` call, I pass in `Expression.Constant(passedInGenericQueryable)` so it seems like I gave it an instance. I never give it a Constant of `Person` so how is it able to access the property?

Comment: Constant is a concrete instance of object. It is not your case, you build Lambda Expression, which have input parameters. It is virtual delegate which "should be' applied to each record. Nothing will be applied. EF Core will use this information for building SQL.

Comment: Are you saying that that since I'm describing a delegate I can just make up whatever I want (as long as the join is valid) because linq to entities will translate it into the correct sql? Would it be fair to say that this wouldn't work on `IEnumerable<Person>` because it would try to execute the delegate rather than use it to build sql? Also, why do I even need `Expression.Constant(passedInGenericQueryable)`? Shouldn't the `Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "Address")` make it unneeded?

Comment: Actually it should be `passedInGenericQueryable.Expression` instead of constant.